# Compiler errors in WINNT.H after retargeting solution to latest SDK (10.0.18362)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, platform-sdk

After retargeting my solution to SDK version 10.0 (latest installed version) (10.0.18362) and upgrading my projects to platform toolset v142, I am receving compile-time errors in **winnt.h** as follows:

```
...\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h(18611,19): error C2143: syntax error: missing ':' before 'constant'
...\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h(18611,22): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ':'
...\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h(18611,22): error C2059: syntax error: ':'
...\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h(18612,29): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before ':'
...\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h(18612,29): error C2059: syntax error: ':'
...\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h(18613,9): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
...\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h(18614,5): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
...\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h(18615,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
```

This happens purely as a result of the upgrade. What might I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I had defined a `CR` macro in my code like so:

```
#define CR "\r"
```

It was overwriting the name of a struct data member in the Windows SDK header.

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_ARM64_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY {
    DWORD BeginAddress;
    union {
        DWORD UnwindData;
        struct {
            DWORD Flag : 2;
            DWORD FunctionLength : 11;
            DWORD RegF : 3;
            DWORD RegI : 4;
            DWORD H : 1;
            DWORD CR : 2;           // <-- conflicting member
            DWORD FrameSize : 9;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} IMAGE_ARM64_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY, * PIMAGE_ARM64_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY;
```

The same thing happened to [this fellow asking for help on the MSFT dev boards](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/699469/visual-studio-2019-1622-error-c2143c2059-in-winnth.html).

You'll have to rename your `#define` or avoid upgrading the SDK.